# Rolling Two Dice To Get a 7

Tags: java

I'm trying to get dice to roll until a 7 is obtained and then keep a running total of how many times it took to get a 7 through the trials. Once all trials have been completed, I need to average them. Right now I put in the number of trials but then it runs the first part of the 'for loop' ("Trial #1:") and then doesn't do anything else. What am I missing? This is being done in the dr.Java IDE.

***Edit* Semicolon after while loop was initial problem. Now I'm running into a different one. The loop produces the same output (shown here).
Enter the seed value for the random number generator:

[1]

Enter the number of trials:

[10]

Trial #1: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Trial #2: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Trial #3: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Trial #4: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Trial #5: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Trial #6: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Trial #7: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Trial #8: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Trial #9: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Trial #10: 10 rolls to roll a 7.

Average 1.0 rolls to roll a 7 over 10 trials.**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Geometric {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create the Scanner and the Random number generator using a given seed
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the seed value for the random number generator:");
    int seed = scnr.nextInt();
    Random r = new Random(seed);

    //TODO: complete the program
    System.out.println("Enter the number of trials:");
    int trials = scnr.nextInt();

    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int diceAdded = 0;
    for (int i=1;i<=trials;i++) {
      System.out.print("Trial #" + i + ": ");

    while (diceAdded != 7) {
        int dice = r.nextInt(6)+1;
        int dice2 = r.nextInt(6)+1;
        diceAdded = dice + dice2;
        count++;
    }
        System.out.println(count + " rolls to roll a 7.");
        sum = count;
      }
    double average = (sum/trials);
    System.out.println("Average " + average + " rolls to roll a 7 over " + trials + " trials.");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: Please do not continuously edit your question to reflect new questions and developments. If you have a new question (even if it's related to your original problem), create a new question. Remember that Stack Overflow is not aimed at helping just you, but rather, creating a resource that helps programmers with specific issues over the course of time. To that end, asking people to hit a moving target is counterproductive, even if it helps you in the short run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the typo you made for the semicolon already pointed out, you do not reset your variables inside of your `for` loop, so each iteration will execute on the same values every single time.

Fix this by moving your `count` and `diceAdded` variables into the `for` loop:

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of trials:");
int trials = scnr.nextInt();

int sum = 0;

for (int i=1;i<=trials;i++) {
  System.out.print("Trial #" + i + ": ");
  int count = 0;  
  int diceAdded = 0;
  while (diceAdded != 7) {
    int dice = r.nextInt(6)+1;
    int dice2 = r.nextInt(6)+1;
    diceAdded = dice + dice2;
    count++;
  }
  System.out.println(count + " rolls to roll a 7.");
  sum += count;
}
```

In addition, note that I changed `sum = count` to `sum += count`, which will add the counts all together, instead of resetting the value to previous iteration's value of `count`.

Thanks for @jrook for pointing out your average function is operating on integer division.  You can fix that by casting one of the values to `double` like so: `double average = ((double) sum / trials);`.  So now not only whole numbers are outputted.

**Output:**

```
Enter the seed value for the random number generator:
121
Enter the number of trials:
5
Trial #1: 15 rolls to roll a 7.
Trial #2: 19 rolls to roll a 7.
Trial #3: 9 rolls to roll a 7.
Trial #4: 2 rolls to roll a 7.
Trial #5: 2 rolls to roll a 7.
Average 9.4 rolls to roll a 7 over 5 trials.
```

Comment: Also `double average = (sum/trials);` is bound to eventually produce wrong results because of the integer division.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of stopping in "Trial #1:", is that your `while` is stopping right away because the semicolon.

Change `while (diceAdded != 7); {` to `while (diceAdded != 7) {`.